# .net core RouteData pattern matching

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, url-routing

I'm trying to match a route using the routedata object that's returned from the HttpContext.GetRouteData() method in asp.net core.

Assuming an endpoint of 'http://localhost/dogs/breed' exists, what would be the best way to check that the route data on the current httpcontext matches that endpoint?

As an example the simplest way would be:

```
var matches = string.Equals((string) routeData.Values["controller"], "dog",
                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                   && string.Equals((string)routeData.Values["action"], "breed", 
                       StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

This feels fairly inelegant to me, is there a better way to inspect this data in order to pattern match on the current context?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### This is arguably more elegant:

```
var actual = HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values;

var expected = new RouteValueDictionary {
    { "action", "Breed" },
    { "controller", "Dogs" },
};

return !expected.Except(actual).Any();
```

That will match routes to the `Dogs` controller and its `Breed` action.

#### We can also get type safety:

```
var actual = HttpContext.GetRouteData().Values;
var expected = new RouteValueDictionary 
{
    {
        "action", nameof(ValuesController.Get) 
    },
    {
        "controller", nameof(ValuesController)
            // remove the "Controller" suffix
            .Remove(nameof(ValuesController).Length - nameof(Controller).Length)
    },
};

return !expected.Except(actual).Any();
```